# Is there any built-in function to calculate percentage in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, percentage

I m facing a problem to write a SQL query to get result in % mode, I am familer with `SUM()` and `COUNT()` functions of SQL Server but facing problem to implement logic inside query I want result in below form:-

```
UserName---  % of AccepectResult----   % of RejectResult
```

My table structure is like this with two columns `Name` (UserName) and `Result` :

```
NAME     Result
---------------
USer1       A
USer1       A
USer1       A
USer1       R
USer1       R
USer1       A
USer2       A
USer2       A
USer2       A
USer2       A
USer2       R

A - Accepted Result
R - Rejected Result
```

I'm trying to write this query like this..

```
select * into #t1  from 
(
    select UserName , count(Result) as Acc
    from Test where result = 'A'
    group by UserName 
) as tab1

select * into #t2 from 
(
    select UserName , count(Result) as Rej
    from Test where result = 'R'
    group by UserName 
) as tab2

select #t1.UserName , 
      #t1.Acc , 
      #t2.Rej , 
     (#t1.Acc)*100/(#t1.Acc + #t2.Rej)  as AccPercentage,
     (#t2.Rej)*100/(#t1.Acc + #t2.Rej)  as RejPercentage

 from #t1
 inner join #t2 on #t1.UserName = #t2.UserName


drop table #t1

drop table #t2
```

Is there any other way to write this query and any built-in function for calculating percentage in SQL Server?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You do not require to join table. Instead you can use `SUM` or `COUNT` function like this:

Using `SUM` Function:

```
SELECT Name, 100 * 
SUM(CASE WHEN Result = 'A' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)/COUNT(result)
AS Accept_percent
,100 * 
SUM(CASE WHEN Result = 'R' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)/COUNT(result)
AS Reject_percent
FROM t
Group by Name;
```

Or using `COUNT` Function:

```
SELECT Name, 100 * 
COUNT(CASE WHEN Result = 'A' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END)/COUNT(result)
AS Accept_percent
,100 * 
COUNT(CASE WHEN Result = 'R' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END)/COUNT(result)
AS Reject_percent
FROM t
Group by Name;
```

Or using `SubQuery`:

```
SELECT Name, 100 * 
(SELECT COUNT(result) FROM t WHERE result='A' And Name = main.Name)/COUNT(result)
AS Accept_percent
, 100 * 
(SELECT COUNT(result) FROM t WHERE result='R' And Name = main.Name)/COUNT(result)
AS Reject_percent 
FROM t main
Group by Name;
```

## [*See this SQLFiddle*](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b949f/7)

Answer (score 0):

No there isn't. You will have to multiply by 100 and divide your two numbers explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
select username, (100 * sum(case result when 'A' then 1 else 0 end) / count(*)) as accepted, 
                 (100 * sum(case result when 'R' then 1 else 0 end) / count(*)) as rejected 
    from test
    group by username
```